# how to add two android arcgis SDK in one project?

Tags: android, sdk, arcgis

i want add 2 version of arcgis android sdk.verion 10.2.8 and 100.0.0 . but i have error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/libruntimecore_java.so
>       File1: C:\Users\falah\AndroidStudioProjects\SelectMaP\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.esri.arcgis.android\arcgis-android\10.2.8-1\jni
>       File2: C:\Users\falah\AndroidStudioProjects\SelectMaP\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.esri.arcgisruntime\arcgis-android\100.0.0\jni

some feature there is in 10.8 and another version.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem and I noticed ESRI staff already stated you can't have both libraries (10.x and 100.x) at same time in same proyect.

Please check: https://community.esri.com/thread/190689-how-to-add-two-sdk-of-arcgis-android-in-project

So... you should choose only one.

Good news: They already ported almost all the classic features to their newer library, so 100.x should be a safe bet.